# Counter in the app doesn't function as intended

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, if-statement, jsx

```
 if(this.state.current=== this.state.dataSet.length-1){
    if(this.state.choice.correct===2) { 
      this.setState({IsPassed:true})
    }
    else if(this.state.choice.incorrect===2){ 
      this.setState({IsFailed:true})
  }}else{
    this.setState({current:this.state.current+1})
}
```

```js
import React from 'react'

function IsPassed() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2 className="IsPassed">You are Passed!</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default IsPassed;
```

```js
import React from 'react'

function IsFailed() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2 className="IsFailed">You are Failed</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default IsFailed;
```

```js
 handleClick(choice){
    if(choice===this.state.dataSet[this.state.current].correct){
      this.setState({correct:this.state.correct+1})
    }
    else{
      this.setState({incorrect:this.state.incorrect+1})
    }
    /*this.setState({isFinished:true})*/
    if(this.state.current=== this.state.dataSet.length-1){
        if(this.state.correct===2) { 
          this.setState({IsPassed:true})
        }
        else if(this.state.incorrect===2){ 
          this.setState({IsFailed:true})
        }
  }
    else{
        this.setState({current:this.state.current+1})
    }    }
```

[total 3 questions but it displaying 4 entries containing correct and incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbmWQ.png)
Whenever i am selecting the correct option first and then incorrect ,so when the third time when i select the correct option, it counts initially from 0 and displays the message of you are passed

Comment: Can you share the code where you increment/decrement correct/incorrect counters?

Comment: can you add the code to the question please

Comment: ok i am doing it

Comment: `this.state` doesn't update immediately after calling setState, you'll need to use local variables within your fn to store the incremented value, then set it to state and use the local variable for the comparison

Comment: done editing the code

Comment: if(this.state.correct===2) { 
          this.setState({IsPassed:true})
        }

since you have this, once you select correct, incorrect and correct, your correct count is 2 and you set the state to isPassed:true

Comment: @SinanYaman when i'm selecting correct, incorrect and correct again, the correct initializes again after choosing incorrect and hence correct goes to 3 and incorrect goes to 1, so 4 times the count goes instead of 3 (because questions are 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can call this inside componentDidUpdate() function to see if the test is finished and the user has passed or failed:

```
if(this.state.current=== this.state.dataSet.length-1){
        if(this.state.correct===2) { 
          this.setState({IsPassed:true})
        }
        else if(this.state.incorrect===2){ 
          this.setState({IsFailed:true})
        }
    }
}
```

And in the handleClick:

```
    if(choice===this.state.dataSet[this.state.current].correct){
          this.setState({
           correct:this.state.correct+1,
           current: this.state.current+1
          })
        }
        else{
          this.setState({
           incorrect:this.state.incorrect+1, 
           current:this.state.current+1
           })
        }
```

Comment: You can call this inside componentDidUpdate() function to see if the test is finished and the user has passed or failed:   Can you elaborate this point??